# Непонятно почему прекращается работа программы

Tags: c

У меня есть такой код. По сути он должен запускаться, но после ввода строки программа прекращает роботать. Открывает другое окно и там так и сказано. Интересно то, что если написать код без ввода даных, то программа работает. Подскажите, в чем проблема.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[80];
    scanf_s("%s", str);
    printf("Length is %d", strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы про третий параметр функции scanf_sзабыли, там должен быть размер второго параметра.